# Uso del ISNULL en SQL de Sybase

Tags: sql, script, null, sybase

en primer lugar gracias por su tiempo, quiero saber si hay solución para este problema, quizás ustedes me puedan ayudar.

Estoy realizando una consulta de SQL en Sybase, hasta que llegue a un dato donde debo de consultar el ID de un cliente, el problema con este campo es que cuando es un cliente genérico el sistema no inserta ningún registro, normalmente utilizaría una función tipo ISNULL(ColumnName, 0) AS idcliente, pero encontré que el sistema no deja el campo como NULL sino que deja el campo en blanco por lo tanto este comando no me funciona.

Alguna idea de cómo puedo resolver esto? Lo que quiero lograr es insertar el código 'CF' cuando el campo IDCLIENTE esté vacío, dejo script e imagen para sustentar mi caso.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

```
SELECT 
"micros"."fcr_invoice_data"."Extrafield9" AS 'SERIEFACTURA',
"micros"."fcr_invoice_data"."Extrafield10" AS 'NUMEROFACTURA',
"micros"."fcr_invoice_data"."Extrafield11" AS 'UUID',
"micros"."trans_archive_dtl"."T_rvc_seq" AS 'BODEGA', 
"micros"."fcr_invoice_data"."MicrosBsnzDate" AS 'FECHA',
30 AS 'DIASCREDITO',
"micros"."fcr_invoice_data"."MicrosBsnzDate"+ 30 AS 'FECHAVENCIMIENTO',
ISNULL("micros"."fcr_invoice_data"."CustomerID", 'CF') AS 'CODIGOCLIENTE',
"micros"."chk_dtl"."emp_seq" AS 'CODIGOVENDEDOR',
"micros"."fcr_invoice_data"."Subtotal1" AS 'TOTALENCABEZADO',
"micros"."fcr_invoice_data"."Subtotal4" AS 'PROPINA',
"micros"."trans_archive_dtl"."D_chk_cnt" AS 'CANTIDAD',
"micros"."trans_archive_dtl"."MIDEF_obj_num" AS 'CODPRODUCTO',
"micros"."trans_archive_dtl"."D_chk_ttl" AS 'VALORVENTAXUNIDAD',
"micros"."trans_archive_dtl"."D_chk_cnt"*"micros"."trans_archive_dtl"."D_chk_ttl" AS 'MONTOTOTAL'FROM 
( "micros"."chk_dtl" LEFT OUTER JOIN 
"micros"."trans_archive_dtl" ON "micros"."chk_dtl"."chk_seq" = "micros"."trans_archive_dtl"."C_chk_seq" ) LEFT OUTER JOIN 
"micros"."fcr_invoice_data" ON "micros"."chk_dtl"."chk_num" = "micros"."fcr_invoice_data"."MicrosChkNum"WHERE 
MIDEF_Name IS NOT NULL AND D_chk_ttl > 0 AND "micros"."fcr_invoice_data"."MicrosBsnzDate" = '2020-11-05 00:00:00.000'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si el campo es `varchar` puedes utilizar `trim()` y validar si es vacío.

Comment: Fijate que no logre hacerlo con trim pero ya le encontré solución. Lo publicaré en un momento.

Answer (score 0):

Les comento que encontré la forma de hacerlo mediante un CASE. Siendo la consulta de ese campo en específico de la siguiente manera:

```
(CASE "micros"."fcr_invoice_data"."CustomerID" WHEN ' ' THEN 'CF' ELSE "micros"."fcr_invoice_data"."CustomerID" END) AS 'CODIGOCLIENTE',
```